# Cannot center marker's info window?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to center the marker's info window because it's fully visible. There are two images showing the problem. On the first the title of the info window is not visible and on the second image is how it should look like. Here is my code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition();
            Point mappoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(markerLocation.latitude, markerLocation.longitude));
            mappoint.set(mappoint.x, mappoint.y - 100);

            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(mappoint));

            mMap.animateCamera(cu, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (marker != null)
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line:

```
returning false;
```

Should be:

```
returning true;
```